# I want to use laravel without PDO

Tags: linux, laravel, pdo

Has any way to use lavarel without PDO. I want remove PDO on my Linux. My embedded linux use postgres but no PDO. How to remove PDO for lavarel? Has any config to remove PDO?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Laravel Database Connectors, Eloquent and/or Query Builder, no, there is no way of using it without PDO, but if you'll not use Eloquent or QueryBuilder in your application, yes, you can just remove PDO from your system.